# How to combine all columns of a dataframe into one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with all columns named "Standard Deviation", 265 columns in total. 
I want to combine them all in this way:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   a0  b0  c0  d0
1   a1  b1  c1  d1
2   a2  b2  c2  d2
3   a3  b3  c3  d3
4   a4  b4  c4  d4

becomes 

    A
0   a0
1   a1
2   a2
3   a3
4   a4
5   b0
6   b1
7   b2
8   b3
9   b4
10  c0
11  c1
12  c2
13  c3
14  c4
15  d0
16  d1
17  d2
```

Stack() combines them in a different way.

I've tried concat but get an error:

```
df = pd.concat(df['Standard Deviation'], ignore_index=True)

>>TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Here is what the dataframe looks like:

```
Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  ... Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation  Standard Deviation
0   5.7735e-05  N/A 5.7735e-05  N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A ... N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
1   0.00050914  N/A 0.000337704 N/A 8.27103 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A ... N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
2   7.61074e-05 N/A 1.35277e-05 N/A 1.73205 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A ... N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
3   2.74651e-05 N/A 1.85562e-05 N/A 270 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A ... N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
```

Comment: How about `df.melt()`?

Comment: Yes with drop() that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
 column = pd.Series(df.values.flatten()) # or df if you want
```

Oprtion 2:

```
 df.melt().drop('variable',axis=1)
```

Comment: IIUC, `df.values.flatten()` is equivalent to `df.stack()`

Comment: What is 'variable'?

Comment: By default `pd.melt` return a df with columns `variable` and `values`. Variables contains your original columns names. You can change that with `df.melt(var_name = 'myname')`

Comment: Thanks it returned a column '0' instead of 'variable'. Works tho

Answer (score 1):

You can melt the dataframe and remove the label column called 'variable'.

```
df.melt().drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't have a column called 'variable', they are all called 'Standard Deviation'. And the single column should be called 'Standard Deviation' after also.

Comment: @Mitch I know, the column 'variable' is automatically created. You can adjust the column name afterwards with df.columns = [names].

Comment: Thanks it created a column called '0' instead of 'variable', this worked for me.